# Website where one could find list of certified notebooks for OpenSolaris?

Tags: opensolaris, laptop

Is there website where one could find list of certified notebooks for OpenSolaris 2009.06?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a list maintained by the vendor, but there is a community driven hardware compatibility list maintained on Sun's website. You can find it at:

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/hcl/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Since the OpenSolaris install disc is a LiveCD it's easy enough to non-destructively test on any hardware you can get your hands on.  If you know someone with a laptop you're considering or if you buy things retail, just pop in the CD and reboot. Everything worked out of the box on my Lenovo Thinkpad X300 btw.